# Python 3 rock Paper Scissors loops

Tags: python

When I run the program :

> ```
> R,S or P?
> Rock
> you threw : R
> your enemy threw : R
> >>>
> ```

The last line of code does not show up

```
if user_choice == computer_choice :
        print ("tie!")
```

Do you know what should I do?

Thank you!

```
import random


def main():

      user_choice = input("R,S or P?\n")
      user_choice = user_choice.lower()
      if user_choice == "rock" or user_choice == "r"  :
            print("you got R")
      elif user_choice == "p" or user_choice == "paper" :
            print("you got  P")
      elif user_choice == "s" or user_choice == "scissors" :
            print("you got S")
      else :
            print ("wrong answer!")

      computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
      if computer_choice == 1 :
            print("your enemy chose  R")
      elif computer_choice == 2 :
            print("your enemy chose  P")
      else :
            print("your enemy chose S")


      if user_choice == computer_choice :
            print ("tie!")


main ()
```

Comment: How would a string like `'r'`, `'s'` or `'p'` ever be equal to a number like `1`,  `2` or `3`?

Comment: `if user_choice == "rock" or user_choice == "r"` ==> `if user_choice[0] === 'r':`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Comment: If you continue to vandalize your post like this, there's a good chance it'll result in a suspension.

Answer (score 1):

User choices are strings, computer choices are integers, so the comparison always fails.

Answer (score 1):

change from:

```
computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
  if computer_choice == 1 :
        print("your enemy threw : R")
  elif computer_choice == 2 :
        print("your enemy threw : P")
  else :
        print("your enemy : S")

if user_choice == computer_choice :
        print ("It's a tie!")
```

to:

```
computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
  if computer_choice == 1 :
        computer_choice = 'r'
        print("your enemy threw : R")
  elif computer_choice == 2 :
        computer_choice = 'p'
        print("your enemy threw : P")
  else :
        computer_choice = 's'
        print("your enemy : S")

if user_choice[0] == computer_choice :
        print ("It's a tie!")
```

Comment: It's not sufficient as a (correct) `user_choice` may be e. g. `"rock"`.

Comment: @MarianD How can the answer be `"rock"` when it asks `"R,S or P?\n"`?

Comment: @RickyKim: The program allows other choices. See the code: `if user_choice == "rock" or user_choice == "r":`.

Comment: @RickyKim, do you think that all users are so disciplined that the programmer may rely on them?

Comment: @James Yes, the edited code should now work for all those weird inputs lol

Comment: @James it gets the first element (e.g. 'r' in 'rock')